# Why does $\vec \nabla \times \vec A = 0$ imply $\vec A = - \nabla B$

Tags: vectors

Why does $\vec \nabla \times \vec A = 0$ imply $\vec A = - \nabla B$ where $\vec A$ is a vector field and $B$ is a scalar field?

I see this in my Electricity and Magnetism textbooks all over the place and I just took it for granted. Is this a theorem or does it come from one?

I can verify in my head that this is valid, but I would love some context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does zero curl imply a conservative field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635850/does-zero-curl-imply-a-conservative-field)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why curl free field implies existence of potential function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638099/why-curl-free-field-implies-existence-of-potential-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\vec{A}$ has a simply connected domain, any closed loop $C$ encloses a surface $S$ on which Stokes's theorem gives $\int_C \vec{A}\cdot d\vec{r}=\int_S\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{A}\cdot d\vec{S}=0$. But these vanishing loop integrals imply any infinitesimal $\vec{A}\cdot d\vec{r}$ is following a scalar field's value through space, i.e. $\vec{A}=-\vec{\nabla}B$ as required.

Comment: N.B this only applies if your domain is simply connected!

Comment: As explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields), $(x\vec{j}-y\vec{i})/r^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^3\backslash O$ is a famous example of when the result fails for a domain that isn't simply connected.