# Does $\operatorname{curl}(\mathbf{a})=\mathbf0$ always imply $\mathbf{a}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}b$? Is it always conservative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

There are two questions here at MSE that are very similar to mine, namely [Does zero curl imply a conservative field?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635850/does-zero-curl-imply-a-conservative-field?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Why does $\vec\nabla\times\vec A=\vec0$ imply $\vec A=\vec\nabla B$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798424/why-does-vec-nabla-times-vec-a-0-imply-vec-a-nabla-b?noredirect=1&lq=1) But they don't fully answer my question.

The accepted answer for the first linked question claims that $\operatorname{curl}(\mathbf a)=\mathbf0$ does not imply that $\mathbf a$ is conservative but the point that confuses me is that once you extend from the field defined over a simply connected subspace

[image]

to the "non conservative" version over a space that is not simply connected

[image]

then there is no continuous scalar field whose gradient can produce such a vector field. There would be a discontinuity at the line where they join.

With this, can we say that if $\mathbf a\colon U\subset\mathbb R^m\to\mathbf{R}^m$ is a vector field (with $m=2, 3$) then $\operatorname{curl}(\mathbf a)=\mathbf 0\nRightarrow\mathbf{a}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}b$ unless $U$ is simply connected?

Also, if $\mathbf{a}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}b$ can we say that $\mathbf{a}$ is conservative even if $U$ is not simply connected?

Comment: The answer to both your questions is *yes*. (What's your definition of a conservative force field? Some people use being a gradient field as the definition. Equivalent is path independence of the work line integral.)

Comment: I was referring to path independence of line integrals.

Comment: Yes, the equivalence should be in your textbook. If not, you can check out my [YouTube lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rkocp63mteY&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd&index=88). See, in particular, MATH 3510 day 31, starting approximately around minute 10.

Comment: Thank you, that is illustrative (although I am not very versed with the language of differential forms I was able to understand the outline of the proof). And about the first question, do you know how it can be proved?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's a counterexample — rather than a proof — that's required. The usual example is $\vec F = (-y,x)/(x^2+y^2)$ on $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$.

Comment: But how would you go about showing that there exists no scalar field $b$ such that $\vec\nabla b = \vec F$? That's my main question

Comment: Ahh, do you use the fact that it's non-conservative and then the equivalence shown in the video?

Comment: Think about your pictures above. What's a closed path around which you get positive work?

Comment: Right. By the Fundamental Theorem for Line Integrals, gradient fields do zero work around a closed curve.

Comment: Thank you very much, professor.